# How would an electromagnet function within an MRI?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, biomedical-engineering, medical-devices

For the purpose of this situation. Lets say there are 4 small electromagnets within a MRI. All of them activate at the same time. The entire setup is comprised up of non ferrous metals. The metals within the core of each solenoid are only magnetized when the current is applied to the electromagnet. The MRI is on.

What would happen to the non ferrous metal when it is suddenly magnetized? Would it immediately succumb to the power of the MRI? Could the current be turned off quickly enough for the MRI to not immediately pull the non ferrous metal towards it?

From my understanding, the non ferrous metal would instantly lose its magnetic properties once current is no longer affecting the electromagnet so the MRI would have no affect on the metal.

Comment: If you're not planning on doing this as part of a project, "What-if" questions go within "World-building" with a hard science tag, or Physics with a "theoretical" tag.  Ask them over there and they can probably help you out significantly.